# quartz.properties not loaded in grails app's embedded jetty

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I've enabled jdbcStore in QuartzConfig

```
quartz {
    jdbcStore = true
    autoStartup = true
}
```

and provided quartz.properties in `grails-app/conf` directory:

```
...
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
...
```

The problem is that when I run grails in local dev environment with `grails rA` those properties are ignored and I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'RebillJobSimpleTrigger' for 'com.payment.rebill.RebillJob' job:Bad value for type long : \xaced00057.....
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1241)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$5.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1147)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3670)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:242)
```

In live environment everything works ok, however I'm unable to run the project in embedded jetty.

**Elaboration:**

The exception is thrown because my custom quartz.properties are ignored (Thus instead of PostgreSQLDelegate the StdJDBCDelegate is used which is unable to read BLOB from DB).

I use quartz grails plugin version 0.4.2 which contains empty `grails-app/conf/quartz.properties` and I think there is some class loader issue which loads this empty file instead of my own quartz.properties file.

Looking into the plugin the properties file is configured in [QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/blob/0.4.2/QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy)'s spring bean:

```
quartzScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean) {
            configLocation = "classpath:quartz.properties"
            ...
```

(There is some spring bean builder magic which converts the `"classpath:quartz.properties"` String to spring's Resource class, since SchedulerFactoryBean's configLocation property is of type Resource).

When I debug the initialization on line 554 of [SchedulerFactoryBean](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context-support/3.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.java#554) the configLocation leads to empty file despite my quartz.properties are not empty.

When I manually change the quartz spring bean to read file from different location everything works:

```
quartzScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean) {
            configLocation = "classpath:data/quartz.properties"
            ...
```

However I can't change the quartz plugin itself. Do you have any idea how to fix this locally ?

I use grails version 2.1.2